# How to get ios style for ionic modal

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

im trying to get a modal ios effect but when i use a normal modal i cant get it, 
this is the effect with black border in the top 
[image]

Any ideas how to get this effect with ionic react ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
you need to create this variable

```
const pageRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
```

then make the mode propertie in modal = 'ios'

in your curren page put this reference

```
<IonPage ref={pageRef} >
      ...
      ...
```

Last step is in the modal properties put this

```
presentingElement={pageRef.current!}
```

more info here
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#swipeable-modals